# Autoupdater stops on safeboot/uefi prompt (15.04 -> 16.04)

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 15.04, update-manager

I used Software updater to upgrade 15.04 -> 16.04. The installation process stopped when i was prompted about safe boot and uefi options in terminal in autoupdater gui. I cannot use that terminal to click  or write any command. Any suggestion how to continue update process or safely stop it?